# ValueError while using cv2.findContours() in python. -> not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 2)

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

Getting an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "motion_detector.py", line 21, in <module>
        (_, cnts, _) = cv2.findContours(thresh_frame.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE) 
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 2)
```

Having problems with detecting contours in an image. Have been double checking from the tutorial and also looking from stack overflow to understand where I miss something, but can't find the solution. Using Python 3.6.4 and OpenCV 4.0.0. Thanks for the help!

Code here:

```
import cv2, time

first_frame = None

video = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while True:
    check, frame = video.read()

    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    gray = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray,(21,21),0) 

    if first_frame is None:
        first_frame = gray 

    delta_frame = cv2.absdiff(first_frame, gray)
    thresh_frame = cv2.threshold(delta_frame, 30, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]
    thresh_frame = cv2.dilate(thresh_frame, None, iterations = 2) 

    (_, cnts, _) = cv2.findContours(thresh_frame.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

    for contour in cnts:
        if cv2.contourArea(contour) < 1000: 
            continue
        (x, y, w, h) = cv2.boundingRect(contour)
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 255, 0), 3)

    cv2.imshow("Gray Frame", gray)
    cv2.imshow("Delta Frame", delta_frame)
    cv2.imshow("Threshold Frame", thresh_frame)
    cv2.imshow("Color Frame", frame)

    key = cv2.waitKey(1)
    print(gray)
    print(delta_frame)

    if key == ord('q'):
        break

video.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows
```

Answer (score 11):

I also encountered same problem, if you are using an old tutorial `cv2.findContours()` function returns 3 value but if you are using later versions it returns 2 value so you can remove first variable assignment and use like that

```
cnts, _ = cv2.findContours(thresh_frame.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
```

Answer (score 3):

Well in Python version 2 `findContours()` used to return 3 values so we save it in `(_,cnts,_)` however in python 3 it returns 2 values which are countours and hierarchy. so we need to save it in `(cnts,_)`. 
So for python 2 people the code goes like:

```
(_,cnts,_) = cv2.findContours(thresh_frame.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
```

And for Python 3 people the code goes like :

```
(cnts,_) = cv2.findContours(thresh_frame.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
```

Its just about version guys,nothing to worry just change it this way and I am sure you will get the desired output.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using cv 4.0 then `findContours` is returning two values. See the example [here](https://docs.opencv.org/4.0.1/d4/d73/tutorial_py_contours_begin.html) or the documentation for [findContours](https://docs.opencv.org/4.0.1/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#gadf1ad6a0b82947fa1fe3c3d497f260e0). The function signature looks like this:

**contours, hierarchy   = cv.findContours(image, mode, method[, contours[, hierarchy[, offset]]])**

Comment: Changing `(_, cnts, _)` to `contours, hierarchy` helped. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed problem is with that line:

```
(_, cnts, _) = cv2.findContours(thresh_frame.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
```

According to [documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html) `cv2.findCountours` returns two things: `contours, hierarchy`, so when you try to unpack it to `(_, cnts, _)` having 3 elements error appears. Please try to replace mentioned line with

```
cnts = cv2.findContours(thresh_frame.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)[0]
```

and check if that would solve you problem.